# Running a For Loop over billion times in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, int

Is there a way to run a for loop where

```
i > INT_MAX_VALUE
```

I know that INT_MAX_VALUE is equal to 2,147,483,647

I can't imagine it being impossible but if it is there a work around?

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: have you thought about using a long?

Comment: Or `BigInteger` class...

Comment: Or an unsigned int?  Or a long long?   Or a int64_t from `#include <stdint.ht>`

Comment: or just `for(int i = 0; true; i++)`

Comment: @selbie- See the tag of `java`, you probably posted about C.

Comment: Is this for Project Euler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are *other* data types with more range than a simple `int`. For example:

```
for (long num = 0; num < 1000000000000L; num++) ...
```

That'll get you up to about 9 quintillion (`9,223,372,036,854,775,807`). If you need more than that, you may want to consider not so much the *range* as the *time* it's going to take to run the loop - at a billion iterations per second, it'll take a little over 290 years :-)

Comment: I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes. I see now that apparently it was a much more simple question than I thought. Thank you very much @paxdiablo

Answer (score 4):

Looping has nothing to do with integer types in general.But in this case you can simply use long type instead of int type.

```
for(long i=0;i<max;i++){  
// as max is long type and max can take values upto 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
//code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must make `i` a `long`, so it can take values greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  If you're using a literal number in your loop's condition, append 'L' to use a `long` literal so you can use a literal value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger bi_ = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000");
    for(;true;) {
        System.out.println(bi_);
        bi_ = bi_.add(new BigInteger("1"));
        if(bi_.equals(new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000000000"))) {
            System.out.println(bi_);
            break;
        }
    }
```

```
 Above for loop start from 1 quintillion and end with 1 octillion
// One quintillion --> 10^18 = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000
// One octillion   --> 10^27 = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

Comment: You should explain your code only answer. Code only answers are often downvoted and may even be deleted.

Comment: As there are limit with Integer, Long and Double here the example is using BigInteger to very big number like One quintillion. This means to see the completion of this for loop must wait few many years.